# Bash echo variable in string always has spaces

Tags: bash, echo

I am currently working on a Mac OS X software update check script/plugin for Nagios, so that I can monitor my Mac Mini and Mac Pro machines, whether they have any updates available or not.

I created a variable called `swUpdateCheck` and assigned the check command to it, including some `grep` and `awk`, so that I can work with the output at the end. Since I don't always want to call the os update command, I just exported the output to a text file `update.txt` and am currently using the text file for building the final script.

This is my variable:

```
swUpdateCheck=`cat update.txt | grep -B1 recommended | grep -v recommended | awk '{gsub(/^[[:cntrl:][:space:]]+|^\-+|\*\s/,"");}NF>0 1' | wc -l`
```

Content of the Text file:

```
   * Security Update 2018-004-10.12.6
--
   * Safari11.1.2Sierra-11.1.2
--
   * iTunesX-12.8
```

Now my issue is, that whenever I call the variable it scans through the file and should give me a number of lines at the end when I echo it. It does give me a number when using a simple echo but as soon as I combine the variable with a string, it adds spaces in front of the number and I don't understand why.

Normal echo of `swUpdateCheck`:

```
$ echo $swUpdateCheck
3
```

Echo `swUpdateCheck` in a string:

```
$ echo "There are $swUpdateCheck Updates available."
There are        3 Updates available.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the variable"? Calling is something you do with functions, not variables.

Comment: From your output it looks like `swUpdateCheck` contains a number of spaces followed by `3`. What's the problem?

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong. `wc -l` is padding its output, but leaving the expansion unquoted in `echo $swUpdateCheck` effectively strips the padding.

Comment: The additional spaces are being added by the `wc` command. I suggest you collapse your pipeline and do everything in awk. It can keep a counter in a variable that you print in your `END` block. Alternately, use `printf` to format your output instead of displaying it with `echo`.

Comment: @melpomene The solution from @Kamil Cuk helped me with my problem. And sorry if I caused any confusion by saying "called", that was my German thinking...

@chepner I assumed that `wc -l` was causing it but was unsure about it. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Auch auf deutsch werden Funktionen aufgerufen, nicht Variablen. :-)

Comment: Dann bin ich anders, als andere :-) Ich sage nämlich auch Variable aufrufen. Am Ende wusste man, was ich meinte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`swUpdateCheck` has spaces in it, not just `3`. As you are not escaping the variable in `echo $swUpdateCheck` spaces get reinterpreted and 3 get's printed out. If you enclose the variable in `"`, as in `echo ".... $swUpdateCheck ..."` spaces will not be ignored. Observe the output with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ echo
+ echo

$ swUpdateCheck="       3"  # assigment with spaces in it
+ swUpdateCheck='       3'
$ echo           3  # leading spaces get ignored
+ echo 3
3
$ echo $swUpdateCheck  # just printing '3', this is the same as above line
+ echo 3
3
$ echo "$swUpdateCheck"  # with "
+ echo '       3'
       3
$ swUpdateCheck=${swUpdateCheck// /}  # remove spaces using bash or use sed 's/ //g' or tr -d ' ' or other
+ swUpdateCheck=3
$ echo "$swUpdateCheck"   # now swUpdateCheck is without spaces, it will work
+ echo 3
3
$ echo "There are $swUpdateCheck Updates available."
+ echo 'There are 3 Updates available.'
There are 3 Updates available.
```